# how do dart "Map" and "==" operator works

Tags: dart

[dart playground](https://dartpad.dev/?)

```dart
main() {
  final a = A(1);
  final b = A(-1);
  print(a == b);
  print(a == a);
  final x = {a: 3, b: 5};
  print(x);
  x[a] = 0;
  print(x);
  x[a] = 0;
  print(x);
}

class A {
  final int x;
  A(this.x);

  @override
  bool operator ==(other) {
    if (other is! A) return false;
    return other.x == -x;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => x.hashCode;
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'A<$x>';
  }
}
```

i found

```
true
false
{A<1>: 3, A<-1>: 5}
{A<1>: 3, A<-1>: 5, A<1>: 0}
{A<1>: 3, A<-1>: 5, A<1>: 0, A<1>: 0}
```

i would like to understand what exactly is happning, is it a bug, is it a breaking point, do all higher level languages have this?
and most importantly.
is dart checking each map-entry before updating, in other words, does it have O(n) complexity? because i assumed for maps to have O(1) complexity, to do Object(address) => value mapping, so i though first dart looks at address as key in Map and if it finds (which it should have) then updates it, else looks for key object that matches by "==" sign. also look at another example

```dart
main() {
  final a = A(1);
  final b = A(1);
  print(a == b);
  print(a == a);
  final x = {b: 5};
  print(x);
  x[a] = 0;
  print(x);
  x[a] = 0;
  print(x);
}

class A {
  final int x;
  A(this.x);

  @override
  bool operator ==(other) {
    if (other is! A) return false;
    return other.x == x;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => x.hashCode;
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'A<$x>';
  }
}
```

and logs are as following

```
true
true
{A<1>: 5}
{A<1>: 0}
{A<1>: 0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a lookup on a hash table (which is the default implementation for a `Map`), a hash table must:

1. Hash the key.
2. Check for existing elements with the hashed key.
3. Because the hash table must assume that hash collisions are possible, if any elements are found by step 2, their unhashed keys must *also* be checked for equality to the target key.

Because your keys violate the property that equal keys have the same hash code (and conversely, keys with the same hash code likely compare equal), you end up with a situation where the hash table never finds matching elements.

Objects that compare equal logically must have the same hash code.  When you violate that logical premise, you'll end up with illogical consequences.  Don't do that.

Comment: That also means that if you change the hash code to `get hashCode => x.abs();`, it will start working! You will get hash collisions, but that only affects performance, not correctness. -- In other words, the only requirement for *correctness* of hash codes is that equal values must have equal hashes, different values having different hash codes is for performance. (And therefore `int get hashCode => 4; // Random number` is valid, but *sloooow* for large maps.)